# What is the best wording for a sentence with two present participles?

Tags: verbs, present-participles

The sentence I'm correcting reads: Thank you for considering supporting our gala...

What is the best way to re-phrase this? 
"Thank you for considering to support..."?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The rest of the sentence would probably give the context necessary for an  answer.

Comment: Thank you. To abbreviate, the sentence would read: Thank you for considering supporting our gala.

Comment: It's not something that would normally be said with any type of phrasing. Typically, it would be *thank you for your consideration* or *thank you for your support*, and the context would be known. The active question form would be *Would you like to support X?* or *Would you consider supporting X?* As I've never heard the combination of the two words in this way (in any form), both phrasings sound equally odd to me.

Comment: *Thank you for your gala-support consideration* sounds better to me. But that's relative.

Comment: i don't think there's anything wrong with the sentence as it is

Comment: (strictly, they are gerunds, not participles)

Comment: @JasonBassford I also thought the phrasing was odd, but lo, people actually do write "[Thank you for considering supporting ...](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-e&ei=LCi-XPf3J6KxggfKx5noAw&q=%22thank+you+for+considering+supporting%22&oq=%22thank+you+for+considering+supporting%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4249.6174..8671...0.0..0.101.1141.13j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......33i10.ajnpRQgg3NM)."

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is about right. They are not yet committed to supporting the gala but you would like them to. This is reason to thank them for considering.

For rephrasing it may be enough to say; Thank you for your support of our gala. By assuming their support you may get them to provide it. If you leave in *considering* they will be reminded of reasons they have not to support it.